# How to verify results of spied function (callThrough)

Tags: node.js, typescript, jasmine, nestjs

I want to verify/assert the results of spied function. I'm using nestjs framework with jasmine. I create a jasmine spy on a method i want to "spy" on, that is, eavesdrop args and response/exception. However, I can't access return value of spied method.

Let's say I have an emitter and listener and I want to assert that my listener throws an exception when a DB operation fails.

Listener:

```
  onModuleInit() {
    this.emitter.on('documentDeleted', d => this.onDocumentDeleted(d));
  }

  @CatchAndLogAnyException()
  private async onDocumentDeleted(dto: DocumentDeletedEventDTO) {
    this.logger.log(`Deleting document with id '${dto.id}'...`);

    const result = await this.ResearchHearingTestModel.deleteOne({ _id: dto.id });
    if (!result.ok) {
      throw new DataAccessException(
        `Deleting document with id '${dto.id}' failed. Model.deleteOne(id) result: ${result}`,
      );
    }
    if (result.n < 1) {
      throw new DocumentNotFoundException(`Deleting document with id '${dto.id}' failed.`);
    }

    this.logger.log(`Deleted document with id '${dto.id}.`);
  }
```

Test:

```js
      const mockId = 123;
      const spyDelete = spyOn(model, 'deleteOne').and.returnValue({ ok: 1, n: 0 });
      const spyOnDeleted = spyOn(listener, 'onDocumentDeleted');
      spyOnDeleted.and.callThrough();

      await emitter.emit('documentDeleted', new DocumentDeletedEventDTO(mockId));

      expect(spyOnDeleted).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(spyDelete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(spyDelete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ _id: mockId }));
      expect(spyOnDeleted).toThrow(DocumentNotFoundException);
```

So when debugging, I can see `spyOnDeleted["[[Scopes]]"][0].spy.calls.mostRecent["[[Scopes]]"][0].calls[0].returnValue` is a promise i'm probably looking for, but I can't access it or verify on it.

And when I run the test, this is the output:

```
    expect(received).toThrow(expected)

    Expected name: "DocumentNotFoundException"

    Received function did not throw

       95 |       expect(spyDelete).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
       96 |       expect(spyDelete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.objectContaining({ _id: mockId }));
    >  97 |       expect(spyOnDeleted).toThrow(DocumentNotFoundException);
          |                            ^
       98 |     });
       99 |   });
      100 | });
```

I've seen [CallThrough injected spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919057/callthrough-injected-spy) and several other questions that are similar, but I'm still hoping it's possible to spy on callThrough methods and eavesdrop on in/out of it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`toThrow` cannot be used on spies. You can use spies to mock behavior or use the actual behavior with `callThrough` and then make sure the method was called with specific parameters. But a spy will not have information about the result it produced (value or error) so you cannot set expectations on it.

If you want to test the behavior of `onDocumentDeleted` you have to either test it indirectly by observing the effects of the method. In your case (with `@CatchAndLogAnyException`), it seems to write to the log!? So you can spy on the log and expect it to be called with the error message. Or alternatively, you test the method directly by making it public.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
That is in alignment to what I've seen so far. But testing the method by its indirect effects is not what I want here.. It might give both false positives and false negatives. In this case, changing the logger or my decorator could break the tests for listener.
I don't like the suggestion to make the method public since I believe the methods shouldn't be made public just for the purpose of testing. Production code shouldn't adapt to tests, but other way round, imho.

Comment: Regarding the `toThrow` and `toReturn` not capturing output of the spied method - I question the design decisions behind jasmine spies. What are spies supposed to do, if not to spy on the methods they attach to? Also, they could update their documentation at least to reflect this astonishing decision..
I understand your answer and thank you for it. However I'm still looking for a solution that would be in line with my previous comment.

Comment: I see your conflict but if testing it indirectly is not an option for you then you have to make it public somehow. Tests only have access to public members because you should only test the public interface. As long as the behavior of the interface doesn't change, you shouldn't have to change your test. If you access private methods or properties, this does not hold true. Of course, in reality sometimes testing the public interface is not possible. But then the only option I see is making the method (or extracted class) public or using a Javascript hack like `service['privateMethod'](params)`.

Comment: And I'm not sure if I totally agree with the "don't change your code for tests" paradigm. For sure, you shouldn't clutter your production code with test helpers that otherwise wouldn't be needed. But some code is better-suited for unit testing than other. And having your tests in mind when you  make design decisions for your code is not a bad idea. The whole concept of TDD is based on the idea of creating well testable code; it's a design pattern.

Comment: Sorry I can't offer a solution that is satisfying for you. Maybe someone else has a better idea on this. :-)

Comment: Come to think about it again, your point about testing private/public methods applies well here. I was reluctant to raise the visibility of those methods precisely because they're in the listener which can be silent observer, hiding [its methods] and listening for events to trigger itself. However, once I decide to have it's behavior tested, I must somehow make direct invocation available for testing in order to test its logic in isolation. [Either making them public inside it or delegating those methods to other interfaces.]
Thank you for clearing up this design pattern misunderstanding.